# Why don't all my data from the database display onto my JTextfield

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a huge program but my 'find product' button does not display the prices of each product typed into the description JTextfield, the output only show one row from the database and ignores the other rows from the database.

I have another problem by my 'Add customer' button why don't my new data that are inserted into the JTextfields save onto the actual database that i have?

Here my Code:

```
 package electronic.invoice.entry;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class ElectronicInvoiceEntry extends JFrame implements 
     ActionListener 
  {
    JLabel Name = new JLabel("Name");
    JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
    JTextfield Address = new JLabel("Address");
    JTextField address = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel City = new JLabel("City");
    JTextField city = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel Description = new JLabel("Description");
    JTextField description = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel Province = new JLabel("Province");
    JTextField province = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel Zip = new JLabel("Zip");
    JTextField zip = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel ProductCode = new JLabel("Product Code");
    JTextField productcode = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel Invoice = new JLabel("Invoice Number");
    JTextField invoice = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel CustomerNum = new JLabel("Customer Number");
    JTextField customernum = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel ProductBought = new JLabel("Product Bought");
    JComboBox productbought = new JComboBox();
     JLabel Quanity = new JLabel("Quanity");
     JTextField quanity = new JTextField(20);
     JLabel Payment = new JLabel("Payment");
     JTextField payment = new JTextField(20);
     JLabel Price = new JLabel("Price");
     JTextField price = new JTextField(20);
     JLabel Deposit = new JLabel("Deposit");
     JTextField deposit = new JTextField(20);
     JLabel AllProducts = new JLabel("All Products: ");
     JComboBox allProducts = new JComboBox();
     JButton AddCustomer = new JButton("Add Customer");
     JButton FindProduct = new JButton("Find Product");
     JButton ListProduct = new JButton("List Product");
     JButton AddInvoice = new JButton("Add Invoice");
     JButton ShowInvoice = new JButton("Show Invoice");
     JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
     JButton WriteInvoice = new JButton("Write Invoice");
     JButton Next = new JButton("Next");

public ElectronicInvoiceEntry() {
    super.setTitle("Electronic Invoice Entry");
    super.setBounds(500, 200, 500, 450);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    pane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    this.getContentPane().add(pane);

    pane.add(Name);
    pane.add(name);
    pane.add(Address);
    pane.add(address);
    pane.add(City);
    pane.add(city);
    pane.add(Description);
    pane.add(description);
    pane.add(Province);
    pane.add(province);
    pane.add(Zip);
    pane.add(zip);
    pane.add(ProductCode);
    pane.add(productcode);
    pane.add(Invoice);
    pane.add(invoice);
    pane.add(CustomerNum);
    pane.add(customernum);
    pane.add(ProductBought);
    pane.add(productbought);
    pane.add(Quanity);
    pane.add(quanity);
    pane.add(Payment);
    pane.add(payment);
    pane.add(Price);
    pane.add(price);
    pane.add(Deposit);
    pane.add(deposit);
    pane.add(AllProducts);
    pane.add(allProducts);
    pane.add(AddCustomer);
    pane.add(FindProduct);
    pane.add(ListProduct);
    pane.add(AddInvoice);
    pane.add(ShowInvoice);
    pane.add(Exit);
    pane.add(WriteInvoice);
    pane.add(Next);

    this.setVisible(true);

    AddCustomer.addActionListener(this);
    ListProduct.addActionListener(this);
    ShowInvoice.addActionListener(this);
    WriteInvoice.addActionListener(this);
    FindProduct.addActionListener(this);
    AddInvoice.addActionListener(this);
    Exit.addActionListener(this);
    Next.addActionListener(this);

    AddCustomer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/orion", "root", "");
                    System.out.println("Connection" + conn);
                    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                    String query = ("INSERT INTO `customer`(`Customer_Number`, `Name`, `Address`, `City`, `Province`, `Zip`, `Deposit`)"
                            + " VALUES ('Customer_Number', 'Name', 'Address', 'City', 'Province', 'Zip', 'Deposit')");
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                    ps.setString(1, customernum.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, name.getText());
                    ps.setString(3, address.getText());
                    ps.setString(4, city.getText());
                    ps.setString(5, province.getText());
                    ps.setString(6, zip.getText());
                    ps.setString(7, deposit.getText());

                    ps.execute();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ElectronicInvoiceEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
            }   
        }
    });
    ListProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/orion", "root", "");
                System.out.println("Connection" + conn);
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT `Description` FROM `product` ORDER BY Description");

                while(rs.next()) {
                    productbought.addItem(rs.getString("Description")); 
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ElectronicInvoiceEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }
    });
    ShowInvoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    WriteInvoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    FindProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/orion", "root", "");
                System.out.println("Connection" + conn);
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT`Description`, `Price` FROM `product` WHERE `Description` IN "
                       + "('Toaster','Hair dryer','Car vacuum')");

                while(rs.next()) {
                  description.setText(rs.getString("Description"));
                  price.setText(rs.getString("Price"));

                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ElectronicInvoiceEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }
        }
    });
    AddInvoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    Next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                electronicInvoiceEntryTransaction frame = new electronicInvoiceEntryTransaction();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    });

}//end of constructor

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElectronicInvoiceEntry e = new ElectronicInvoiceEntry();
}//end of main method

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

public class electronicInvoiceEntryTransaction extends JFrame {


        JLabel Name = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel CustomerNumber = new JLabel("Customer Number");
        JTextField customernumber = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel Balance = new JLabel("Balance");
        JTextField balance = new JTextField(20);
        JButton CheckBalance = new JButton("CheckBalance");
        JButton Deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
        JButton Calculate = new JButton("Calculate Payment and Deposit");
        JButton Transaction = new JButton("Transaction");

    public electronicInvoiceEntryTransaction() {
        setTitle("Electronic Invoice Entry - Transaction");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(300, 300, 700, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        pane.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.getContentPane().add(pane);


        pane.add(Name);
        pane.add(name);
        pane.add(CustomerNumber);
        pane.add(customernumber);
        pane.add(Balance);
        pane.add(balance);
        pane.add(CheckBalance);
        pane.add(Deposit);
        pane.add(Calculate);
        pane.add(Transaction);

        CheckBalance.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        Deposit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            /* INSERT INTO `account`(`Name`, `Customer_Number`, `Balance`)"
                        + " VALUES ('Name','Customer_Number','Balance')*/   
            }
        });
        Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        Transaction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }//end of constructor
}//end of class electronic transaction

 }//end of main class
```

Comment: Your find product query has hard coded values instead of using the value from the description text field.  The result set loop is replacing the text of the previous record in the text fields with the values from the current record every time.  You must gather all the values and call setText() once.  Finally, your insert query is an improper prepared statement because you should use ? within the statement as a placeholder for the values you want to insert by calling ps.setString(1, ...)

Comment: @Palamino The prepared statement i added the "?" but my new data still don't save to the actual database, it does the same thing in my above code.  For my find product query im not sure what you mean by gather the values and call setText() once

Comment: Even when i do ps.setString(1, " ")  it still does not add my data to the database

Comment: Modify your insert query to resemble String query = "INSERT INTO `customer`(`Customer_Number`, `Name`, `Address`, `City`, `Province`, `Zip`, `Deposit`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";  Then modify your code to set the values such as ps.setString(1, customernum.getText());
 ps.setString(2, name.getText()); ps.setString(3, address.getText()); ...etc.  In the catch(SQLException ex) block, log any exceptions so you know what is going wrong, and you should use int count = ps.executeUpdate(); and verifying that the count == 1 instead of calling ps.execute().

Comment: @Palamino It worked now..... i will remember this in the future. Thanks

Comment: Just need to figure out what happening for the setText()

Answer (score 0):

Modify your FindProduct action listener as follows to gather descriptions and prices for all result set rows:

```
FindProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       Connection conn = null;
       try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/orion", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connection" + conn);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT `Description`, `Price` FROM `product` WHERE `Description` IN ('Toaster','Hair dryer','Car vacuum')");

            StringBuilder sbDesc = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbPrice = new StringBuilder();
            while(rs.next()) {
                sbDesc.append(rs.getString("Description")).append("\r\n");
                sbPrice.append(rs.getString("Price")).append("\r\n");
            }
            description.setText(sbDesc.toString());
            price.setText(sbPrice.toString());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ElectronicInvoiceEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                try { conn.close(); } 
                catch(Exception e) { Logger.getLogger(ElectronicInvoiceEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e); }
                finally{ conn = null; }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did exactly what your code is and my output when i type in "Toaster" it displays all my prices and products within its textfields. it don't show just one price with one description

Comment: That because the SQL query is exactly the same as your original question.  You have to modify the SQL query WHERE clause to only select criteria you want it to.

Comment: Thats makes sense now Thanks @Palamino